# What is a Module Path Index in Racket

Tags: module, racket, dynamic-linking

Racket has [Module Paths](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=module-path%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._module-path~3f%29%29) (predicate is `module-path?`), [Resolved Module Paths](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=module-path%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._resolved-module-path~3f%29%29) (predicate is `resolved-module-path?`), and [Module Path Indexes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=module-path%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._module-path-index~3f%29%29) (predicate is `module-path-index?`).

I guess a `module-path?` is anything that could plausibly point to a module. And I guess a resolved module path points to an actual module on the system.

But what is a module path index and what does it get me over just a resolved module path?

Comment: Moving this to a comment ;-) Part of the puzzle is that module path indices are semi-interned, which is important for the module system (loading a module twice is a bad idea).

Comment: Yup, they are semi-interned just to help double loading. Although sometimes you actually do want to load a module twice, such as if you are writing DrRacket and you want the module to run whenever the user hits run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **`module-path?`** contains anything that can be `require`d. Could be a `path?`, could be a symbol, could be a submodule path `(submod "food.rkt" lunch)`. See [`require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._require%29%29) in the docs.

A **`resolved-module-path?`** is an "absolute path" to where Racket can find the module (*Note 1*). The grammar for resolved module paths is more limited (i.e., less ambiguous) than for module paths.

A **`module-path-index?`** (MPI) is a delta from one `module-path-index?` to another (*Note 2*). Use `module-path-index-join` to build MPIs (*Note 3*).

- `(module-path-index-join #f #f`) is a delta from the current module to itself.
- `(module-path-index-join "dumplings.rkt" #f)` is a delta from `#f` (the current module) to the relative path `"./dumplings.rkt"` (Yes it's really *path* first, then *base*.)
- `(module-path-index-join "nom-noms.rkt" (module-path-index-join "dumplings.rkt" #f))` is a delta from the current module to `"./dumplings.rkt"` to `"./nom-noms.rkt"`. Racket builds MPIs like this when one file statically requires another --- these can be chained together to find the binding of an identifier.
- `(module-path-index-join '(submod test) #f)` refers to the test submodule in the current module.

Hope that helps.

---

Note 1: If the module is in a file, a resolved path for it is an absolute filepath. If the module is the result of calling `eval` on a syntax object, its `resolved-module-path?` is something else.

Note 2: IMO "module path deltas" would be a better name.

Note 3: `module-path-index-join` accepts a third, optional argument when the first two arguments are `#f`. This lets a module refer to one of its own submodules. You will generally not want to use this feature directly. And instead use [`quote-module-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Source_Locations.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Flocation..rkt%29._quote-module-path%29%29).